# async parse many strings

Tags: c#, asynchronous

lets say i have content of file divided into

```
List<string> contents
```

and now i would like to do some Parse method on the all of contents and in the end i would like to glue them into one variable

```
//after parsing
foreach(var c in content)
wholeContent += c;
```

i've tried something like this:

```
async Task<string> Parse(string content)
{
 //dosth
}

List<Task<string>> tasks = contents.Select(x=> Parse(x));
```

but to do that i must have:

```
async Task Parse(ref string content)
```

but it is not allowed

how to do that?

Comment: if you have an `async Task Parse()` why don't you `await` it?

Comment: The `Parallel` class is much better for this than `async/await`.

Comment: Parsing is usually not an IO-bound operation. You don't want to make it `async` to begin with. You were probably thinking about [parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22924035/11683).

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the string by reference?  Just include the parsed value in the returned task (or if it's not asynchronous, just as the return value of the method).

Comment: It's important to realize that if you parse the strings in parallel you cannot control the sequence in which they are parsed. That can cause inconsistent and unpredictable results if the sequence matters. That doesn't mean you can't process them in parallel. You just need a mechanism to ensure that the original sequence is passed to each operation and to the results so that when it's done you can put them back in the correct sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Parallel class, for instance a simple for loop can be parallelized as such:

```
        List<string> contents = new List<string>();
        contents.Add("55");
        contents.Add("some text");
        contents.Add("a lone 5");

        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> concurrent = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

        Parallel.For(0, contents.Count, i => concurrent[i] = Parse(contents[i]));

        foreach(string s in concurrent.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

And the parse function itself:

```
    public static string Parse(string content)
        {
            return content.Replace("5", "test");
        }
```

Comment: No, this will break because `parsed.Add()` is not thread-safe.

Comment: That's a good point; you can (should) use a concurrent collection instead. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an async problem. Use the Parallel class or PLInq:

```
 var results = contents.AsParallel().Select(c => /* some sync code here */);
```

Answer (score 0):

As another answer pointed out, you probably want to use PLINQ. Assuming you have a function:

```
string Parse(string str) { }
```

You can parse and combine the strings like this:

```
var result = contents.AsParallel().Select(Parse).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
```

This uses `Select` to map your strings through your Parse function, and `Aggregate` to combine them into one string by concatenation.